# Ошибка в сеттере класса. Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

Друзья, учу свифт. Хочу разобраться с сеттером и вычисляемыми свойствами класса. Хкод выдает для класса такую ошибку: `Cannot convert value of type '[String.SubSequence]'`

Для вот этой строки:

```
let array: [String] = newValue.split(separator: " ")
```

Объясните почему так? Вот мой класс:

```
class Persone {
    var name: String
    var lastName: String
    var fullName: String {
        get {
            return name + " " + lastName
        }

        set{
            let array: [String] = newValue.split(separator: " ")
            self.name = array[0]
            self.lastName = array[1]
        }
    }

    init (name: String, lastName: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь ошибки никакой нет. Результат `split` не массив `String`, а массив `Substring`. Для Вашего примера можете просто убрать тип переменной:

```
let array = newValue.split(separator: " ")
```

Либо маппить в массив `String`:

```
let array: [String] = newValue.split(separator: " ").map{String($0)}
```